# putty cut and paste problems. 1) in unix it has to be visible, 2) paste works, but only the first time

Tags: putty, clipboard, copy, paste

I've been using putty for years, every day.  I have a new laptop (w10) and I can't figure this out.

1. cut and paste from unix to unix (highlight using mouse then right click) only works if the highlight is visible.  For instance if I vi, highlight, exit, then right click nothing is pasted.  If I highlight from the visible terminal buffer, no problem.
2. Cut and paste from windows works fine.  But if I paste the same clipboard a second time, it's gone/ nothing pasted.

I've tried all different combinations from 'Selection', I have it set to: Compromise (Middle extends, Right pastes), the default.

Maybe this is some kind of windows clipboard security feature, not sure.  Cut and paste works normal in windows.

I did try uninstall, reinstall putty.  I even tried and older version of putty.

Comment: recently I was using an SSH connect to a staging server (not one of my normal stable) and it would not paste (windows > putty) unless I manually invoked the shell in the session. Never bothered to set it, but see for example ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/how-to-change-from-csh-to-bash-as-default-shell ) My point being that it may not be *strictly* under putty's control

Comment: Thanks.  I agree it may not be putty doing this, (I think it is).  But I don't see why which shell I'm using would matter.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to resolve the putty issue.  By changing settings I can cut and paste from Unix to Unix but not windows, or have the behavior already described.  I'm not sure if it is my desktop or a change in putty.  Maybe putty was changed as a result of this: https://etherealmind.com/putty-fixing-right-click-paste/.

I work on linux and unix often and cut and paste is something you just expect to work.

I downloaded kitty.  The cut and paste works the way putty used to.  So I am switching to kitty.